# How to combine arrays according indexes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two 2d arrays:

```
var ar1 = [];
var ar1[0] = [];
var ar1[0][0] = 1;
var ar1[0][1] = 2;
var ar1[1] = [];
var ar1[1][0] = 3;
var ar1[1][1] = 4;

var ar2 = [];
var ar2[0] = [];
var ar2[0][3] = 5;
var ar2[0][4] = 6;
var ar2[1] = [];
var ar2[1][5] = 7;
var ar2[1][6] = 8;
```

How can I get the combined array that will look like:

```
var ar1[0][0] = 1;
var ar1[0][1] = 2;
var ar1[1][0] = 3;
var ar1[1][1] = 4;
var ar1[0][3] = 5;
var ar1[0][4] = 6;
var ar1[1][5] = 7;
var ar1[1][6] = 8;
```

I tried:

```
ar1.push(ar2);
```

but this puts whole ar2 to the first empty row of ar1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to `forEach` over the second array, and `Object.assign` each subarray onto the appropriate index in the first:

```js
var ar1 = [];
ar1[0] = [];
ar1[0][0] = 1;
ar1[0][1] = 2;
ar1[1] = [];
ar1[1][0] = 3;
ar1[1][1] = 4;

var ar2 = [];
ar2[0] = [];
ar2[0][3] = 5;
ar2[0][4] = 6;
ar2[1] = [];
ar2[1][5] = 7;
ar2[1][6] = 8;

ar2.forEach((subarr2, i) => {
  Object.assign(ar1[i], subarr2);
});
console.log(ar1);
```

Do note that `var` should only be used when *declaring* a new variable name for the first time - when assigning to an existing variable, omit it. (Also, sparse arrays are rarely a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the second array and assign all values to the first array. For not given array in the second level take an array as default.

```js
var ar1 = [],
    ar2 = [];

ar1[0] = [];
ar1[0][0] = 1;
ar1[0][1] = 2;
ar1[1] = [];
ar1[1][0] = 3;
ar1[1][1] = 4;

ar2[0] = [];
ar2[0][3] = 5;
ar2[0][4] = 6;
ar2[1] = [];
ar2[1][5] = 7;
ar2[1][6] = 8;

ar2.forEach((a, i) => {
    ar1[i] = ar1[i] || [];
    a.forEach((v, j) => ar1[i][j] = v);
});
console.log(ar1);
```